# Escape space in XML xs:list

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

How can you represent an item in an `xs:list` if it contains a space?

**Schema fragment:**

```
<xs:simpleType name="mylisttype">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="mylist" type="mylisttype" />
```

**Example XML fragment:**

```
<mylist>item1 item2 item3 item4</mylist>
```

**Example output:**

```
["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
```

**Example XML fragment (incorrect)**

```
<mylist>Item One Item Two Item Three Item Four</mylist>
```

**Desired output:**

```
["Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three", "Item Four"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible for whitespace to appear in a list item, "even when the item type would in principle allow it":**

> A ·list· datatype can be ·constructed· from an ordinary or ·primitive· ·atomic· datatype whose ·lexical space· allows whitespace (such as string or anyURI) or a ·union· datatype any of whose {member type definitions}'s ·lexical space· allows space. Since ·list· items are separated at whitespace before the ·lexical representations· of the items are mapped to values, no whitespace will ever occur in the ·lexical representation· of a ·list· item, even when the item type would in principle allow it.  For the same reason, when every possible ·lexical representation· of a given value in the ·value space· of the ·item type· includes whitespace, that value can never occur as an item in any value of the ·list· datatype.

From [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2, Section 2.4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#atomic-vs-list)

I can also confirm after testing that escaping space as the XML entity code `&#032;` also does not work, at least in lxml (which is based on libxml2 and libxslt).

(I accepted this answer in preference to the other one because my question was not "how to change the list separator", rather how to escape a space).

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot change spaces as the member separator in `xs:list`, and you cannot escape spaces within the member strings**

Use elements for any more complicated lists that don't work well with `xs:list`.

Read about the [XSD design rationale regarding custom list delimiters here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-xml-schema-comments/2002OctDec/0005.html).

---

Comment: I've read this and I don't want to change the delimiter. For my use case `xs:list` is the most appropriate type. Each string in the list is a short atomic identifier, that may occasionally contain a space character, from a known set.

Comment: @BenSarahGolightly: Answer updated to make clear that there is no escape mechanism for spaces within strings in `xs:list`.  Use elements instead, live without validation for your lists, or validate out of band wrt XSD.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. ty kjhughes, you saved me some wondering.